# Does Amazon DynamoDB GSI's delete GSI rows if the attribute from the main table is used as the key in the GSI?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

Assume I have a table in DynamoDB, if I have the key of my GSI's to be based on an attribute, but then I delete or change the attribute, what is the behavior of the GSI table? Will it delete and change the keys in the GSI table?

TableName: MammalTables
PartitionKey: MammalName
Attribute1: MammalNumberOfLegs
Attribute1: MammalSize

---

GSI name MammalNumberOfLegsGSI
PartitionKey : MammalNumberOfLegs
SortKey:  MammalSize

---

Now assume I have data like this for MammalTables:

MammalName: Human, MammalNumberOfLegs: 2, MammalSize : 5
MammalName: Dog, MammalNumberOfLegs: 4, MammalSize :  1

This means my GSI table now has

MammalNumberOfLegs: 2, MammalSize : 5
MammalNumberOfLegs: 4, MammalSize : 1

If I change MammalSize for Human to 2, does that mean that I will have this in my GSIs?

MammalNumberOfLegs: 2, MammalSize : 2
MammalNumberOfLegs: 4, MammalSize : 1

or does it add on top to be

MammalNumberOfLegs: 2, MammalSize : 5
MammalNumberOfLegs: 2, MammalSize : 2
MammalNumberOfLegs: 4, MammalSize : 1

I think the question can also be phrased as, do GSI's map exactly 1-1 on a row basis with the original table or are there any scenarios where GSIs will make an extra row as opposed to deleting/modifying the existing row?

Comment: Global secondary Indexes are updated by DynamoDB asynchronously  using eventually consistent model . This mean that even though  a data is updated on main table , it will not be instantly reflected in the GSI . However the update to a GSI is a 2 step process  , there will a write operation to delete the previous item and  another to write the new item . so finally we will end up with


MammalNumberOfLegs: 2, MammalSize : 2
MammalNumberOfLegs: 4, MammalSize : 1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Global secondary Indexes are updated by DynamoDB asynchronously  using eventually consistent model . This mean that even though  a data is updated on main table , it will not be instantly reflected in the GSI . However the update to a GSI is a 2 step process  , there will a write operation to delete the previous item and  another to write the new item . so finally we will end up with

MammalNumberOfLegs: 2, MammalSize : 2                                    MammalNumberOfLegs: 4, MammalSize : 1